# How do I create a macro that hides cells when 2 conditions/cells are satisfied (there are multiple target addresses)

Tags: vba

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$E$22" AND  If Target.Address = "$B$22" Then
        If UCase(Target) = "NO" Then
            Rows("23").EntireRow.Hidden = True

        Else
            Rows("23").EntireRow.Hidden = False

        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

For that particular example where there are two options you could use:

```
If Target.Address = "$E$22" OR Target.Address = "$B$22" Then
```

If you have more then look at using a `CASE` statement:

```
Select Case Target.Address
    Case "$E$22"
        'Do Something
    Case "$B$22"
        'Do Something Else
End Select
```

Put in as many as you need, if you need it to do something when it doesn't hit any criteria make your last Case a `Case Else` before the end select

Comment: The answer you provided is if 1 condition is satisfied, I need two

Comment: Read it again, I use an OR condition for two conditions and I give an example of a case statement, if you feel I still have not given you direction post more details of your requirements

Comment: So when I tried doing the OR it would hide the cell for me if either E22 or B22 was a No. However I wanted it to hide a cell only when both were No

Comment: Change the or to and